# Not enough RAM for baking particles

Tags: animation, particles, physics, baking, memory-management

Faced with such a problem - there is a system of particles in settings exposed saving cache to disk next to the file. Also, 400 frame animation of the object. The problem is that baking stops at 100 frames in the Task Manager, the entire memory packed to capacity. Please, help.

Comment: Enable something like [Virtual memory][2] or equivalent on other OS or install more RAM.

  [2]: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-virtual-memory#1TC=windows-7

Comment: You can try to split the particle system into several smaller particle systems and bake them separately.   I've never baked particles so I'm only guessing that this can be done. :)

Comment: Nope, I tried to put as a virtual memory SSD drive, but it did not help. Stopping baking at 100 frames and stops.

Comment: Particle systems are broken, and so on objects. It is also used molecular script.